# javascript manipulating DOM after it's loaded

Tags: javascript

I'm using Stripe for credit card processing.  The Stripe code is a form/script that is placed inline in the HTML code (see below).  I first initialize the Stripe variables to null in a script in the head section of my page.  I'm trying to change these variable after the page is loaded, but I can't seem to do it.  On pageinit, I run a script which sets the parameters.  Clearly the variables are set on pageload and I could really use some help figuring out how to update the values sent to Stripe.

```
    <form id="formPayNow"  onsubmit="return stripePayNow()">
  <button id="customButton">Pay</button>      
      <script>
        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: 'pk_test_Dz',
          image: "https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"  ,
          token: function(token, args) {
            // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
                   cardToken = token.id;                        
                  stripePayNow();        
          }
        });
        document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          // Open Checkout with further options
          handler.open({
            name: 'STRIPE Secure Checkout',
            description: itemDesc,
            amount: itemGross,
            email: userEmail
          });
          e.preventDefault();               
        });
      </script>
</form>
```

EDIT:    Here's what I've tried.....
1.  If I move the initialization of the Stripe variable to after page load (    $(document).on('pageinit', '#showMyInfo',  function(){
then Firebug shows "variable not defined".
2.  If I set it to "null" in the head section of the page, and then later try to manipulate it on pageinit, then I can't.  It stays as "null" when i later call the Stripe form.
            - applogies for being such a newbie !!!

And, if I try  for example.....

```
     document.getElementById("itemDesc").innerHTML = "zzzzzzz";
```

I get a TypeError   is null.

Comment: please show full source.

Comment: When is pageinit called? Why are you putting your script in the head? Is there some reason you can't put it at the bottom of the body?

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle your vars inline this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your vars changes
});
```

This is the best way to manipulate DOM after it's been loaded.

Comment: OK.  Tried that.  I updated my question to reflect all the things I've tried.  THANKS!